# SSH Connection refused wrong port

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ssh, port

I want to connect to remote server through Ubuntu shell. I am using `ssh root@serverIP` in Ubuntu shell but I receive this msg:

```
connect to host xxx.xxx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused
```

This IP is on port 30 not 22. I have also changed the port by using `sudo gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config` to 30 and I think it is saved. But again when I want to log in I receive the same error that connection on port 22 is refused.

Comment: Try connecting to root@serverIP:30

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You need to show exactly what you tried, what errors you received (quoted literally, on its own line), and what configuration you are using

Comment: Some shots in a dark: Maybe you are confusing IP and Port. these are not the same. Try restarting you ssh server: `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the ssh port:

```
ssh -p 30 root@serverIP
```

Also don't move the port just because you think it's more secure. Rather disallow root login, use keyfiles instead of password an maybe run something like fail2ban if the logentries start to annoy you..

Comment: Thank you. It is soved But after entering password I received Permission denied, please try again. Do you know what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you change anything else in sshd_config?

Comment: No nothing else

Comment: do you have some other account you can try to login to?

Comment: or other (physical) access to the server?

Answer (score 2):

If the SSH server is listening on port 30 on the remote host, you need to specify port 30 to your client:

```
ssh -p 30 root@serverIP
```

You can avoid typing it all the time by adding this to your `.ssh/config`  file

```
host MyServer
    user root
    port 30
    hostname serverIP
```

Then you can simply type

```
ssh MyServer
```